# How to increase Transcript buffer size?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am working with Pharo 3 and I use the Transcript to record operations.

However the size of the current buffer is short for my needs. How to increase it? There is characterLimit but this is a method constant and therefore not easy to set up without changing a core package.

I do not want to use NonInteractiveTranscript because I want to stay in the image.

Comment: Are you sure that you are doing things right by vomiting so many data into transcript? Because that's what all the other programming languages propose with logging. Firs for all remember that you can use tests to cover expected behaviour, and then interactively debug parts that fail

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am sure I want to view all my process data as is happening. Test would not make sense because the process could take days, reproducing a test is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no other way to change the buffer length of the Transcript then to modify `#characterLimit` (usually of `ThreadSafeTranscript`). However, try inspecting `ThreadSafeTranscript allInstances` and you'll see that the underlying stream is much longer (50000 something is the write limit there). So, whatever you're printing to Transcript is not actually lost but just not visible.

That being said, using Transcript for extensive output is generally not a good idea because:

- output is cut off (as you've already seen)
- Transcript is really slow when called repeatedly:

  try

  ```
  1 to: 10000 do: [ :i | Transcript show: i ]
  ```

  vs.

  ```
  Transcript show: (String streamContents: [ :stream | 
      1 to: 10000 do: [ :i | stream nextPutAll: i asString ] ])
  ```
- you can't use the output somewhere else (e.g. to write to file or pass along to a method)

In my opinion Transcript is ok for occasional quick debugging but shouldn't be used for anything application related.

Comment: totally agree with Max. You should use a logging framework or write to a file instead.